I solved it with "npx react-native operator", why does it cause problems again?
I used "npx react-native operator".
Resolved an error regarding "Adb".
Resolved an error regarding "Android Studio".
PS D:\\project\> npx react-native doctor

Common 

✓ Node.js - Required to execute JavaScript code 

✓ npm - Required to install NPM dependencies 

● Metro - Metro Bundler is not running

 Android 

✖ Adb - No devices and/or emulators connected. Please create emulator with Android Studio or connect Android device. 

✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code 

✖ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android 

✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation 

✓ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android 

Errors:   2

Warnings: 1 

Attempting to fix 3 issues... 

Common 

✖ Metro   

Could not start the bundler. Please run "npx react-native start" command manually. 

Android 

✖ Adb

√ Select the device / emulator you want to use » Emulator s24u (disconnected) 

✔ Adb 

✔ Android Studio installed successfully in "C:\\Users\\drg\\AppData\\Local\\Android".

run "adb" again, an error occurs
PS D:\project> npx react-native doctor
Common
 ✓ Node.js - Required to execute JavaScript code
 ✓ npm - Required to install NPM dependencies
 ● Metro - Metro Bundler is not running

Android
 ✖ Adb - No devices and/or emulators connected. Please create emulator with Android Studio or connect Android device.
 ✓ JDK - Required to compile Java code
 ✖ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME - Environment variable that points to your Android SDK installation
 ✓ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android

Errors:   2
Warnings: 1

